# issue on product save magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento

When I try to save/edit product from backed getting below error in magento 2.4.6.

Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\CompositeProductStockStatusProcessorPool, Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\CompositeProductStockStatusProcessorPool::__construct(): Argument #1 ($compositeProductStockStatusProcessors) must be of type array, null given, called in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlYvF.png